# Deserializing JSON when fieldnames contain spaces

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm writing a tool to read JSON files. I'm using the NewtonSoft tool to deserialize the JSOn to a C# class. Here's an example fragment:

```
 "name": "Fubar",
 ".NET version": "4.0",
 "binding type": "HTTP",
```

The field names contain spaces and other characters (the .) that are invalid in C# identifiers.
What is the correct way to do this?

(Unfortunately I don't have the option of changing the JSON format.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `JsonProperty` attribute to indicate the name in the JSON. e.g.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "binding type")]
public string BindingType { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

### System.Text.Json

If you're using `System.Text.Json`, the equivalent attribute is [`JsonPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.0):

```
[JsonPropertyName(".net version")]
public string DotNetVersion { get; set; }
```

Example below:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName(".net version")]
    public string DotNetVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("binding type")]
    public string BindingType { get; set; }
}

// to deserialize
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but this did not work for me.  In this example I simply return a null for "BindingType" every time.  I actually found it much easier to just download the Json result as a string and then do something like:

```
  myString = myString.Replace(@"binding type", "BindingType")
```

You would do this as the step before deserializing.

Also was less text by a tad.  While this worked in my example there will be situations where it may not.  For instance if "binding type" was not only a field name but also a piece of data, this method would change it as well as the field name which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize the Json manually, you can do:

```
var jsonString = "{" +
            "'name': 'Fubar'," +
            "'.NET version': '4.0'," +
            "'binding type': 'HTTP'," +
            "}";
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);            
        return Ok(json);
```

Don't forget to include `using Newtonsoft.Json;`